# Use of \p@COUNTER

Tags: macros, counters

When a new counter is defined via `\newcounter`, e.g. `\newcounter{mycounter}` then a command `\p@mycounter` is also defined. I can see this again popping up when setting the `\@currentlabel` in `\refstepcounter`. I wonder what is the purpose of the `\p@mycounter` in this case, and where would one find documentation of such?

Comment: It's documented on `source2e`. You can open it with `texdoc source2e` in a command line and look at `ltcounts.dtx` and `ltxref.dtx`.

Comment: @campa if you want to make an answer to that effect, and shortly comment on its usage, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from *The LaTeX 2e Sources (https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e), File m ltcounts.dtx,
section 22.1: Environment Counter Macros*:

> An environment `foo` has an associated counter defined by
>   the following control sequences:
>
> `\c@foo`
>   Contains the counter’s numerical value. It is
>   defined by `\newcount\foocounter`
>
> `\thefoo`
>   Macro that expands to the printed value of `\foocounter`.
>   For example, if sections are numbered within chapters, and section headings look like
>   Section II-3. The Nature of Counters
>   then `\thesection` might be defined by:
>   `\def\thesection{\@Roman{\c@chapter}-\@arabic{\c@section}}`
>
> **`\p@foo`**
>   **Macro that expands to a printed "reference prefix" of counter `foo`.**
>   Any `\ref` to a value created by counter `foo` will produce the expansion of `\p@foo\thefoo` when the `\label` command is executed. See *file ltxref.dtx* for an extension of this mechanism.
>
> `\cl@foo`
>   List of counters to be reset when `foo` stepped.
>   Has format `\@elt{countera}\@elt{counterb}\@elt{counterc}`.
>
> NOTE:
>   `\thefoo` and `\p@foo` must be defined in such a way that `\edef\bar{\thefoo}` or `\edef\bar{\p@foo}` defines `\bar` so that it will evaluate to the counter value at the time of the `\edef`, even after `\foocounter` and any other counters have been changed. This will happen if you use the standard commands `\@arabic`, `\@Roman`, etc.

Quote from *The LaTeX 2e Sources (https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e), File x ltxref.dtx, section 52.1: Cross Referencing*:

> This is implemented as follows. A referencable counter `CNT` is incremented by the command `\refstepcounter{CNT}`, which sets `\@currentlabel == {CNT}{eval(\p@cnt\theCNT)}`. The command `\label{FOO}` then writes the following on file `\@auxout`:
>   `\newlabel{FOO}{{eval(\@currentlabel)}{eval(\thepage)}}`
>   *[...]*
>   `\label` and `\refstepcounter`
>   The commands `\label` and `\refstepcounter` have been changed to allow
>   `\protect`’ed commands to work properly. For example,
>   `\def\thechapter{\protect\foo{\arabic{chapter}.\roman{section}}}`
>   will cause a `\label{bar}` command to define `\ref{bar}` to expand to something like `\foo{4.d}`. Change made 20 Jul 88.
>
> ```
> 32 \def\label#1{\@bsphack
> 33   \protected@write\@auxout{}%
> 34          {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
> 35   \@esphack}
> 36 \def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
> 37     \protected@edef\@currentlabel
> 38        {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
> 39 }
> ```

When looking at the `\protected@edef` which within `\refstepcounter` redefines `\@currentlabel`, you see that you can, e.g., redefine `\p@⟨counter⟩` so that it triggers toplevel-expansion of `\csname the⟨counter⟩\endcsname`, yielding the control-sequence-token `\the⟨counter⟩` before delivering another control-sequence-token which takes `\the⟨counter⟩` as its argument.

If, e.g., you wish every reference to the number of a section both to be in boldface and to be nested into square brackets, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@section{\expandafter\wrapinsquarebrackets}%
\newcommand\wrapinsquarebrackets[1]{\textbf{[#1]}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{a section}
Reference to the section will be boldface and wrapped into square brackets:
\ref{a section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that the things that come from `\p@⟨counter⟩` will be part of the hyperlink in case of using the hyperref-bundle.

There are situations where this is desired.
But there are also situations where this is not desired:
E.g., in case you intend to use `\p@⟨counter⟩` for automatically creating footnotes with additional remarks that are to accompany the reference, you get so-called nested links: The footnote-mark should be a hyperlink to the footnote-text while at the same time it will be made a part of the hyperlink that leads to the referenced text passage.

Also be aware that `\p@⟨counter⟩` can be used for adding a postfix also—just do something like:

```
\def\p@⟨counter⟩{\expandafter\AddPrefixAndPostfixTo⟨counter⟩}%
\def\AddPrefixAndPostfixTo⟨counter⟩#1{%
  ⟨prefix-tokens⟩#1⟨postfix-tokens⟩%
}%
```

Answer (score 3):

With `\newcounter{foo}` three objects are defined:

1. `\c@foo`, which is a TeX count register;
2. `\thefoo`, the representation of the counter's value;
3. `\p@foo`, the “prefix”;
4. `\cl@foo`, the reset class for `foo` (this won't be discussed).

When one does `\refstepcounter{foo}`, the macro `\@currentlabel` is redefined according to

```
% latex.ltx, line 4199:
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
```

A `\label{baz}` command following `\refstepcounter{foo}` will store the expansion of `\@currentlabel` and the current page in the `.aux` file:

```
% latex.ltx, line 4195:
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

Note that `\protected@write` does full (protected) expansion in order to freeze the current situation, that is, the value of `foo`.<sup>1</sup>

In the case at hand, `\label{baz} will use the value

```
\csname p@foo\endcsname\csname thefoo\endcsname
```

that is, the same as `\p@foo\thefoo`.

The default meaning of `\p@foo` is “nothing”; more precisely, `\newcounter{foo}` performs `\let\p@foo\@empty`.

What's the prefix for? Here's an example, from `article.cls`.

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
```

The counters `enumi`, `enumii`, `enumiii` and `enumiv` are already allocated by the kernel for building enumerated lists at four levels of nesting. Let's assume we are in a third level `enumerate`, fourth item and we do `\item\label{baz}`.

In this case LaTeX will do `\refstepcounter{enumiii}` which causes `\@currentlabel` to be loaded with

```
\p@enumiii\theenumiii
```

which will become, when `\protected@write` enters into action

```
\theenumi(\theenumii)\@roman\c@enumiii
```

If the first level is at item 3 and the second level is at item 2, we'll obtain

```
3(b)iv
```

written in the `.aux` file, so `\ref{baz}` will print “3(b)iv”.

A similar mechanism is used by the `revtex4-1` document class that does

```
\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\def\p@section{}
\def\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\def\p@subsection{\thesection\,}
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\def\p@subsubsection{\thesection\,\thesubsection\,}
\def\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}%
\def\p@paragraph {\thesection\,\thesubsection\,\thesubsubsection\,}
\def\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph}}
\def\p@subparagraph{\thesection\,\thesubsection\,\thesubsubsection\,\theparagraph\,}
```

(this with the `rtx` option, I'll gloss over some details). This way

```
\section{Title}\label{a}
\subsection{Title}\label{b}
\subsubsection{Title}\label{c}
```

will print

> **I Title**
>      **A Title**
>      *1 Title*

but `\ref{a}`, `\ref{b}` and `\ref{c}` will print

> I
>     I A
>     I A 1

(with thin spaces). A similar mechanism is used for equation numbers (but slightly modified).

There is no user interface for defining `\p@<counter>`, probably because this was considered something to be used only in document classes.

Another deficiency is the absence of a *postfix*, which could be handy for postprocessing tokens.

---

*Footnote*

<sup>1</sup> However `\thepage` will not be expanded on the spot because it's explicitly banned to in `\protected@write`; the expansion will happen at the moment the tokens are written to the `.aux` file, when the value of the page number is precisely known.

Answer (score 1):

From the source2e docs obtained by `texdoc source2e` it says in the counter section, page 145 for the version at the time of writing (Version v1.1l 2018/04/22).

> \p@foo Macro that expands to a printed ‘reference prefix’ of counter foo. Any \ref to a value created by counter foo will produce the expansion of \p@foo\thefoo when the \label command is executed. See file ltxref.dtx for an extension of this mech- anism.

The question was answered in the comments and, since no one wrote an answer,
This answer will be a **community wiki** answer if the original answerer does not make one her/himself. This is to remove this question from the
unanswered list. The original answer was by @campa.